# HTTP Server Error 403. Forbidden

Tags: apache, http, networking

I am getting the following error:

```
Forbidden: You don't have permission to access [directory] on this server.
```

I need direct access to this directory and sub folders on that directory so that my Android Application can communicate with it.

I tried putting folders on a Hosting Server and everything works fine.

But, I am doing an academic project and I need to store these folders and scripts on a University Web Server which can talk to localhost locally.

Comment: Do you have admin rights to the server? If so - change the permissions. If not- talk to the admin. Not much we can do to help you...

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to be able to do a directory listing to browse all files in a certain directory? Where does PHP come in play?

Comment: If you don't have access to it, you don't have access to it. Is it denied in the Apache configuration? Where are you trying to store this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.
If you have the possiblity and your server is a linux server, you can change the permissions with something like

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/folder
```

Or completely change the owner with

```
sudo chown -R user /var/www/folder
```

---

2.
Look into the apache configuration files and also the **.htaccess**, if the directory is blocked by

```
Deny from all
```

Or simply not allowed. You could allow the directory by creating a .htaccess file and enter

```
<Directory yourdirectory>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thanks

But this is a University Server we are talking about and certainly I am not an administrator. I am a Student there. 

I know config file can be changed to allow external connections in addition to localhost, but wouldn't they require a static IP even if they allow me to access, which I clearly doubt!!!