# Executing Python script from Java script gives 403 Forbidden error

Tags: apache, file-permissions, http-status-code-403

I am trying to trigger a python script which basically creates a new table in the database.

I have a java script which i am using to trigger the python script.

I am using an Apache server.

```
function triggerscript(){     
    document.write("dddd");
    /*var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status = 200){
    alert("Done")}
    };
    http.open("GET", "/var/www/html/hello.py" , true);
    http.send();*/

    var http = $.ajax({url:"hello.py",success: function(){alert("Yay!!")}});
    document.write("ffff");

}

function formValidate(){
    var x = document.getElementById("valForm").elements[0].value;
    if (x == null || x == ""){
            alert("Name must be filled");
            return false;
    }
    var y = document.getElementById("valForm").elements[1].value;
    if (y == null || y == ""){
            alert("Password must be filled");
            return false;
    }
    document.write("Hey");
    triggerscript();
    document.write("End");
}
```

As you can see, I have two functions

1. triggerscript
2. formValidate

In my `formValidate` function, I am verifying the input from the user and then I am triggering the `triggerscript` function, which has the functionality to trigger the `hello.py` script.

My Java script and python script are in location `/var/www/html/`, for which I have the directory configuration as :

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride None
    AddHandler cgi-script .py .cgi
</Directory>
```

When I debug the flow, I get an `403 Forbidden error`.

Please help !!!!

---

@llamerr : thanks for the suggestion .. but from the initial setup I have my .py file with 755 permission.. I even tried with 777 .. Both didn't work .. 
Though if i have any other javascript which i want to trigger , i do not face any issue with it .. 
My assumption is that somehow the .py file is not being recognised due to some misconfiguration but i am not sure what I can be.
  any other suggestion will be much appreciated ..

Comment: everything you wrote is doesn't matter, you have `403 Forbidden error` which is server error, so check you configuration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Server Error 403. Forbidden](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602331/http-server-error-403-forbidden)

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602331/http-server-error-403-forbidden

Comment: @llamerr : i have check the httpd.conf file, wherein i have the directory configuration as above. Is there anything else which i need to check.

Comment: have you checked permissions as those duplicate answers propose?

Comment: you can check if python/python module or/and it's user/group has access to those files as well. or check logs, maybe they have more info